# wlan0/wlan1 wont show up with ifconfig

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint, ifconfig

I'm running linux mint (virtual machine) and wifi0/wifi1 interface simply wont show up. Wifi is working properly. I have internal wireless card (not USB or anything). Is there a problem with drivers or what?

I'm a CS student and I want to play around with wifi security, so I need it.

Im using Virtual Box.

EDIT: ifconfig shows me ethernet interface and Local loopback

Comment: "Wifi is working properly" on the host or the VM? Secondly: have you added the host's network adapter as an adapter to the VM (NAT/Bridged)?

Comment: Also, can you tag your question with what virtualisation platform you are using - VMWare, VirtualBox etc.?

Comment: wifi is working everywhere, VM too. I'm using VirtualBox.

Comment: You probably won't see a physical "wlan" entry in your ifconfig because the host doesn't present the guest with the physical device - it presents a wired device (hence why you can NAT/Bridged/Host-only) the VM. When you run `ifconfig` what do you get? Can you update your question with the devices listed?

Comment: It shows ethernate interface and local loopback

Comment: And is the eth interface an IP similar to your host IP?

Comment: Not really, not even same subnet. 10.10.10.50 host, 10.0.2.15 VM

Comment: This new information verifies that your VM is operating correctly and using the VirtualBox's integrated DHCP and virtual networking: Do a search through this link for "10.0.2.0" and you'll see that what you're seeing is perfectly normal and is why you don't see the host's physical adapter listed (wlan0 etc.): https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: So you are saying that I either have to buy an adapter or make a dual boot (Linux as secondary OS) ?

Comment: I'm saying that you don't need to do anything.... is there a specific reason you *need* to see the physical device on your VM (which i very much doubt you'll be able to do anyway due to the nature of the hardware abstraction that the VM platform does - only some hardware can be directly communicated with). I.e. the VM platform will only ever expose virtual devices to the VM - I would think that network adapters don't fall into the category as being important enough to be made fully available to a VM...

Comment: Yeah, I need it. I like linux's command prompt more because it allows more stuff and without all interfaces i cant do much. I guess ill just make a dual boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, is not there a problem with the driver, that happen because you are running a guest and it haves his own hardware and is not linked with your phisical or host hardware, it is virtual, even if is paravirtualization your ethernet cards and wireless adapters can't be linked directly with your virtual machine.

To be avaliable to comunicate with the host virtual machine use Virtual Network Adapters and could be set using tree diferent methods.

**That i've quoted from VMWare documentation but it trascend between any virtualization software.**

> **Bridged Networking**
>
> Bridged networking connects a virtual machine to a network by using
>   the network adapter on the host system. If the host system is on a
>   network, bridged networking is often the easiest way to give the
>   virtual machine access to that network.
>
> When you install Workstation on a Windows or Linux host system, a
>   bridged network (VMnet0) is set up for you.
>
> **NAT Networking**
>
> With NAT, a virtual machine does not have its own IP address on the
>   external network. Instead, a separate private network is set up on the
>   host system. In the default configuration, a virtual machine gets an
>   address on this private network from the virtual DHCP server. The
>   virtual machine and the host system share a single network identity
>   that is not visible on the external network.
>
> When you install Workstation on a Windows or Linux host system, a NAT
>   network (VMnet8) is set up for you. When you use the New Virtual
>   Machine wizard to create a new virtual machine and select the typical
>   configuration type, the wizard configures the virtual machine to use
>   the default NAT network.
>
> You can have only one NAT network.
>
> **Host-Only Networking**
>
> Host-only networking creates a network that is completely contained
>   within the host computer. Host-only networking provides a network
>   connection between the virtual machine and the host system by using a
>   virtual network adapter that is visible on the host operating system.
>
> When you install Workstation on a Windows or Linux host system, a
>   host-only network (VMnet1) is set up for you.

or Instead

> **Custom Networking Configurations**
>
> With the Workstation virtual networking components, you can create
>   sophisticated virtual networks. The virtual networks can be connected
>   to one or more external networks, or they can run entirely on the host
>   system. You can use the virtual network editor to configure multiple
>   network cards in the host system and create multiple virtual networks.

[Link to documentation.](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-D9B0A52D-38A2-45D7-A9EB-987ACE77F93C.html)

***UPDATE: Added some basic information from Virtual Box Documentation about Networking.***

> Each of the eight networking adapters can be separately configured to
>   operate in one of the following modes:
>
> **Not attached**
>
> In this mode, VirtualBox reports to the guest that a network card is present, but that there is no connection -- as if no Ethernet cable
>   was plugged into the card. This way it is possible to "pull" the
>   virtual Ethernet cable and disrupt the connection, which can be useful
>   to inform a guest operating system that no network connection is
>   available and enforce a reconfiguration.
>
> **Network Address Translation (NAT)**
>
> If all you want is to browse the Web, download files and view e-mail inside the guest, then this default mode should be sufficient
>   for you, and you can safely skip the rest of this section. Please note
>   that there are certain limitations when using Windows file sharing
>   (see Section 6.3.3, “NAT limitations” for details).
>
> **NAT Network**
>
> The NAT network is a new NAT flavour introduced in VirtualBox 4.3. See 6.4 for details.
>
> **Bridged networking**
>
> This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations and running servers in a guest. When enabled, VirtualBox
>   connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network
>   packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network
>   stack.
>
> **Internal networking**
>
> This can be used to create a different kind of software-based network which is visible to selected virtual machines, but not to
>   applications running on the host or to the outside world.
>
> **Host-only networking**
>
> This can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network
>   interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback
>   interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among
>   virtual machines and the host.

[Link to Documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

You should try an USB adapter, it can be linked with your VM direcly. So you can easy use your Wireless Adapters inside your Machine to Audit Wireless networks and complete your study case.

Another Suggestion you could try [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) there is a complete suite to Pen Testing, where you have a lot of tools success with all your Study Cases.

Comment: Useful, as you've pointed out that the host hardware needs to be added to the VM so it can pick up and use the host hardware, however you are recommending something that the OP doesn't need to do. "You should try a USB adapter" - why, when the onboard hardware can also be shared with the VM by using a NAT adapter or bridged adapter through the virtualisation software?

Comment: @BigChris hi, well ive pointed in this direction because the OP wanted to see this wireless adapters(host ones) inside his VM,  about my recomendation i just folow "Keep an open mind" http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask. so ive felt free to propose an alternative way to see his wifi adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link, but your answer could have included that the OP DOES have options to expose the host's current hardware (network cards, HDDs, ODDs, USBs etc.) to the VM without having to explicitly install additional hardware as a sole solution...

Comment: I just need to see all interfaces on my linux mint (which is installed on VirtualBox). WIFI is working properly on VM too.

Comment: @BigChris, ive updated with more information about virtual adapter configuration.

Comment: @RokDolinar your guest cant show your host virtual adapters because them do not belong to your virtual machine, it uses a virtual adapter prolly linked with NAT or Bridge method to you wireless adapter.

Comment: Is there a way to work around it, or should i install Linux as my second OS?